# Fill down the workbook instead of overwriting the first entry over and over again

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to copy and paste certain rows into a new workbook:

```
Sub ReportCreator()

    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim lrow As Long


    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Pharmas")

    '~~> Destination/Output Workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pharmas").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row


    With wbO
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        '~~>. Save the file

        For iCounter = 2 To lastRow
        If wsI.Cells(iCounter, 4) = "Barr" Then
        wsI.Rows(iCounter).Copy
        End If

        wsO.Range("A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Next iCounter

.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\rrrrr\Desktop\eeee.xls", FileFormat:=56
       End With




End Sub
```

When the code goes down my list, any row with `Barr` in column 4 is copied and then pasted onto the new workbook.

The problem I'm encountering is that it's not pasting down the new workbook for each row it finds. Instead on the new workbook, it just overwrites the first row with newer information. When I debug, the code portion that looks for `Barr` and copies the row is working, but it's not pasting down the workbook, it's just overwriting the first row.

I've tried adding altering the paste code as follows:

```
wsI.Rows(iCounter).Copy
            End If
lrow = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsO.Range("A" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,
```

However, it tells me *Object doesn't support this property or method*.

I am sure the paste code is incorrect but I'm not sure how to change it so it fills down the workbook instead of overwriting the first entry over and over again with each subsequent find of `Barr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this amended code

```
Sub OhYa()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim lrow As Long, rw As Long


    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    'Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    Set wsI = Sheets("Pharmas")

    '~~> Destination/Output Workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    lastRow = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row


    With wbO
        '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        '~~>. Save the file
        With wsI
            For iCounter = 2 To lastRow
                If wsI.Cells(iCounter, 4) = "Barr" Then
                    .Cells(iCounter, 4).EntireRow.Copy
                    rw = wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    wsO.Cells(rw, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                End If

            Next iCounter

            '.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\rrrrr\Desktop\eeee.xls", FileFormat:=56
        End With
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you forgot to reference wsO:

```
lrow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsO.Range("A" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This solution should work, but should be slow. You can run faster by keeping track of the next row in a variable and icrementing it whenever you paste a row.

Comment: I get "pastespecial method of range class failed" error when I try to run it with the above modifications

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are the values then do not use paste but assign the value to the cell directly.

```
lrow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsO.rows(lrow + 1).value =wsI.Rows(iCounter).value
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner! This works perfectly. I ended up using Davesexcel code because I realized I do need the cell formats after all, not just the values